# Bulk importing repositories into a local bitbucket installation

Tags: bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am running into trouble. I am migrating a huge project structure into git - which worked so far. Now I need a solution for bulk importing it into the local bitbucket server. Unfortunately the bitbucket api v1 - which is present on the local installation - does not support this any more. The v2 api is ... well, where is it? Using a 2.0 instead of 1.0 causes 404s. The documentation and examples at atlassian are constantly referring the their cloud solution - which we don't have and which we don't want. So using curl as well as the bitbucket command line client don't do the trick.

Can anybody tell me where I can create new repos via shell?